# find query in array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have items that  looks like this :

```
{
  "arr": [
    "1",
    "2"
  ]
}{
  "arr": [
    "3",
    "1",
    "2"
  ]
}
```

how can I get all items that have for example 2
in arr
I tried

```
collection.find({"arr":{ $in: ["2","3" ] }})
```

but it doesn't return anything

Comment: Depite someone giving you an upvote for this, that is not a valid document structure. So it does not actually look like that, hence why your query fails.

Comment: paste correct json of your items.

Comment: i edit it and its written correct now.
was just copy paste bug

Comment: @user3100708 Both docs are returned when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your problem, you have to use **[$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)** operator:

```
db.collection.find({"arr":{ $all: ["2","3" ] }})
```

it will return below document (it has all of "2" and "3" in it):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54b93487ae194d31f11f08bf"),
    "arr" : [ 
        "3", 
        "1", 
        "2"
    ]
}
```